# Properly capture chagnes of contenteditable <td> in bootstrap-vue b-table

Tags: vue.js, contenteditable, bootstrap-vue, vue-reactivity

So I have this problem with the rendering of contenteditable cells that drives me crazy. I have b-table like this

```
<b-table 
  v-once
  v-if="showTable" 
  :small="true"
  :items="timeSerres" 
  :fields="timeSerriesX"                                
  :primary-key="timeSerriesX[0].key"
  striped hover responsive selectable   
  @focusout.native="editCell"              
>  
</b-table>
```

I am setting :fields like this

```
this.timeSerriesX[j]={
 key:'t-'+diff.toString(), 
 label:this.$moment(this.endDate).add(-diff, 'M').format('MMM-YY'),     
 tdAttr:{contenteditable:true}            
}
```

I am setting :item, like this

```js
this.rowText.split('\t').reverse().forEach(function(element,i_) {                    
 row['t-'+i_]=element
});

this.timeSerres.push(row);
```

To detect editing I capture focusout native event and handle it like this

```js
editCell(event)      
{ 
  var row_index = event.target.parentNode.rowIndex-1
  var cell_index = event.target.cellIndex;        
  var newValue = event.target.innerText;                      

  var row = this.timeSerres[row_index]
  var key = this.timeSerriesX[row_index].key;
  row[key]=newValue;
  
  this.$set(this.timeSerres,this.rowIndex,row);  
},
```

This approach works fine until I hit the corner case. When the cell is initially empty, and then I input data into the table cell, the input will be rendered twice when focus out.
E.g click on empty cell, input "*1*" then focus out the browser will render actually "*11*"; 
Or click on empty cell, input "*ab*" then focus out the browser will render actually "*abab*"

Please help!

Comment: I would recommend using `<b-table-simple>` and it's child helper components to render the table and cells, rather than using `<b-table>` which is much more heavy weight.

Comment: Thank you Troy, now this is my plan, I just cannot properly control subelements in <t-table>